# can we audit the tables in mysql database using envers?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

My project is on struts hibernate 3.  We are using MYSQL database.  can we audit the table using envers?  Which version of jar  of envers can I use?  Please help as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the version that matches that of Hibernate.

We release Hibernate ORM at the same time as we release Hibernate Envers, so their versions should always match one another, at least since the last 3.x release days.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  Actually I am not able to find compatible envers jars for hibernate 3.   can you please provide the link?

Comment: What specific version of Hibernate 3 are you looking for?

Comment: its hibernate3.jar

Comment: I am trying with hibernate-envers-3.6.0.Final and also with hibernate-envers-3.5.0.Final, but with these 2 jars the tables are not created if I use property tag for AuditEventListener.

Comment: And "org.hibernate.HibernateException: org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration" with message "Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 399; columnNumber: 95; Attribute "type" with value "pre-collection-update" must have a value from the list "auto-flush merge create create-onflush delete dirty-check evict flush flush-entity load load-collection lock refresh replicate save-update save update pre-load pre-update pre-insert pre-delete post-load post-update post-insert post-delete post-commit-update post-commit-insert post-commit-delete " " occured while using listener.